Received "uncaught type error cannot read properties of undefined (reading pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions)" with PDFJS
I downloaded from github PDFJS 4.3.146 and installed according to github instructions USING NPM and NPX. I also installed node.js. I then loaded the generated pdf.js into a VisualStudio 2022 project on Windows 10, dropped down to the learning examples, and ran "Hello World" to validate the install and setup.
The first error I got was PDFJSlib was undefined so I added a statement to resolve: let { pdfjsLib } = globalThis;
Now when I run the page, I get an "Uncaught type error cannot read properties of undefined (reading pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions)".
The "Hello, world" title appears on the web page, followed by the Javascript code
I suspect I'm not getting the right setup of pdfjsLib correct but don't know how to fix this.


HTML is

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>'Hello, world!' example</title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <h1>'Hello, world!' example</h1>
    <canvas id="the-canvas" style="border: 1px solid black; direction: ltr;"> 
    </canvas>

    <script src="../../node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.mjs" type="module"> 
    </script>

    <script id="script" type="module">
    //
    // If absolute URL from the remote server is provided, configure the CORS
    // header on that server.
    //
    const url = './helloworld.pdf';
    let { pdfjsLib } = globalThis;
    //
    // The workerSrc property shall be specified.
    //
    pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc =
    '../../node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker.mjs';

    //
    // Asynchronous download PDF
    //
    const loadingTask = pdfjsLib.getDocument(url);
    const pdf = await loadingTask.promise;
    //
    // Fetch the first page
    //
    const page = await pdf.getPage(1);
    const scale = 1.5;
    const viewport = page.getViewport({ scale });
    // Support HiDPI-screens.
    const outputScale = window.devicePixelRatio || 1;

    //
    // Prepare canvas using PDF page dimensions
    //
    const canvas = document.getElementById("the-canvas");
    const context = canvas.getContext("2d");

    canvas.width = Math.floor(viewport.width * outputScale);
    canvas.height = Math.floor(viewport.height * outputScale);
    canvas.style.width = Math.floor(viewport.width) + "px";
    canvas.style.height = Math.floor(viewport.height) + "px";

    const transform = outputScale !== 1
      ? [outputScale, 0, 0, outputScale, 0, 0]
      : null;

    //
    // Render PDF page into canvas context
  //
  const renderContext = {
    canvasContext: context,
    transform,
    viewport,
  };
  page.render(renderContext);
</script>

<hr>
<h2>JavaScript code:</h2>
<pre id="code"></pre>
<script>
  document.getElementById('code').textContent =
      document.getElementById('script').text;
</script>
</body>
</html>



All suggestions on how to resolve this are welcome
Thanks in Advance
Al
